# GCP cloud function double function call

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I created and executed a code similar to this in Cloud Function.

[image]

However, in gcp, the list did not contain any values.

Is that the way it is?
I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there is a doc address related to it.

[image]

Comment: I believe `test()` or  `test2()` is never called. Call the functions before the print().

Comment: can you show the complete function code, and how you deploy it, please?

Comment: Can you show how do you print the array values (or length)? And how do you deploy your functions?

Answer (score 0):

Google's Cloud Functions takes a function provided in the code as an entry point. I used the `test1` function as an entry point and called the test2 function from there.

```py
X = []

def test2 ():

  global X
  X.append(2)

def test1 (self):

  global X
  X.append(1)
  test2()
  print(X)
```

This will return the value of X in the logs.